# Help with method to hollow out existing model. Scaled down Boolean modifier and solidifier modifier have not worked

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

Good morning.

I am trying to figure out how to hollow out an existing model (STL) in blender (model link below).  I'm not asking anyone to do it for me, I am just trying to figure out what keywords I should search in Google to hopefully find a tutorial.  I am basically looking to have the model hollow on the inside, ultimately for 3d printing and hopefully getting some lights in it.  Other models have issues and aren't as well put together as this one, so I am hoping to use it.

I first duplicated the part and then scaled it down to try and use a Boolean modifier but when it scales it is only scaling the overall size.  It doesn't "inset" or reduce the size of the model on each surface evenly.  So this method didn't work.

I tried to use a solidifier modifier but I just ended up with an angry porcupine that exploded.

I know in my CAD software there is a shell command that allows you to basically specify a thickness of the walls and allows you to remove faces.  Is there anything like that in blender that could be used?

Model:
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5842553

Comment: I stopped the download because it appears to try to download 4 files, and smells of spyware.  I suggest you use the [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) link that people normally use.

Comment: I suggest that your include a screen-shot that will draw more attention and clarify what you are seeing.